# Type Variables in type classes

Tags: haskell, generics, types, automata

I have a strange question in relation to type classes. So you can define a basic type class like this:

```
class Property x where
    checkThing :: x -> Int -> Bool
    transformThing :: x -> x
```

If you want to have a type class with multiple parameters you can enable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
```

This will let you do things like:

```
class Property x y where
    checkThing :: x -> Int -> Bool
    transformThing :: x -> y -> Int
```

Here is my problem: So imagine I wanted to write a type class for automata (The kind that accept a language). I would write a type class that looked something like this:

```
class Automata machine where
    isDeterministic :: machine -> Bool
    acceptsInput :: machine -> String -> Bool
```

A automata takes in an input and decides if that input is part of a language. The above class would work for this. But wait this is limited to lists of characters (String) what if I want to generalize by Automata? Well I could add another variable to my class definition:

```
class Automata machine alphabet where
    isDeterministic :: machine -> Bool
    acceptsInput :: machine -> [alphabet] -> Bool
```

Hmm that is okay. But alphabet may have no direct relation to machine. Im in luck though! I can enable:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies #-}
```

And force language to depend on machine

```
class Automata machine alphabet | machine -> alphabet where
```

Ok now when I make an instance of Automata I can require alphabet to be related to the machine. For example:

```
instance Automata (FSM alphabet) alphabet where
```

works, and this correctly

```
instance Automata (FSM alphabet) othertypevariable where
```

gives an error. This is ok but not very generic. For example I have to define an instance for every type of automata, and every type of alphabet they can take. Thats horrible. In addition the functional dependencies does not actually force a relation. You can write:

```
 instance Automata (FSM alphabet) Int where
```

without a compiler error. Here is what would be ideal.

```
class Automata (machine alphabet) where
    isDeterministic :: machine alphabet -> Bool
    acceptsInput :: machine alphabet -> [alphabet] -> Bool
```

If I could specify a particular type parameter on the data instances are being defined for. For example the data that automata could be defined for would look like:

```
data FSM alphabet = FSM [alphabet]
```

or something like that. This would also allow defining single generic instances such as:

```
instance Automata (FSM alphabet) where
```

These examples are a simplified version I am trying to do but a solution for this problem would solve my problem. How could I go about expressing something this? Can I bend type classes to my will? Language extensions are acceptable.

Comment: n.m.'s answer is correct, but your reason why you're not satisfied with the functional-dependency approach doesn't make sense to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Haskell type classes can abstract over arbitrary kinds. This means parameters o type classes can themselves have parameters. Familiar examples include `Functor` and `Monad`, that accept arguments like `[]` or `Maybe`. Here's a way to write write it with a type of `*→*` kind:

```
class Automata machine where
    isDeterministic :: machine alphabet -> Bool
    acceptsInput :: machine alphabet -> [alphabet] -> Bool

data FSM alphabet = FSM [alphabet] -- just an example, you need more 
                                   -- stuff to define a real FSM...

instance Automata FSM where 
    ...
```

Using `{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}` the kind of `machine` can be made explicit:

```
class Automata (machine :: * -> *) where
```

Comment: Perhaps you mean that classes can abstract over arbitrary kinds, which is the correct foil to concrete types. Type constructors are the foil to arbitrary type-level terms. e.g. `Bool`, `Maybe`, and `State` are type constructors, but `State s` -- though it is not a concrete type and has a higher kind -- is _not_ a type constructor.

Comment: @DanielWagner You can call it a type constructor expression. See [the article that started it all](http://www.cs.tufts.edu/comp/150GIT/archive/mark-jones/fpca93.pdf) (pdf). But maybe you are right and this is an outdated term.